# Merging duplicate data within singular dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am using pandas library

I have a large database with hundreds of data partial duplicates (one or two columns are the same but one of the two holds additional information). 
I want to merge the duplicated instances while retaining the row with the most information. I can only figure out how to merge two databases, not data within a singular database.

Example:

```
Col 1: Name, Col 2: Age, Col 3: Other, Col 4: Other, Col 5: Other

Row1   Aaron Miser, 32, Plumber, 4 Children, NaN
Row2   Aaron Miser, 32, NaN, NaN, NaN        
Row3   Aaron Miser, 32, NaN, NaN, NaN, likes football
```

I need to identify duplicates of Col 1 (in this example Aaron Miser), then merge duplicate instances so that the merged row now has the most data available for duplicated instance. So there is only 1 retained row and it now shows all available information:

Aaron Miser, 32, Plumber, 4 Children, likes football

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda series: series.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill'))
```

If you want to remove duplicates and reset the index, add a `.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)` after that.

**Note:** this assumes that  the `Name` column provides a unique key and that there are no rows with conflicting information.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This didn't seem to merge rows when duplicate column 'name' is identified.

Comment: @Zuckerbrenner do you mean when there are multiple groups of rows with the same `Name` value but which refer to different instances?

Comment: Yes; sorry for confusion. master database is a result of many combined/merged databases (all with the same key column of 'name' but some with additional columns of data) and so there are duplicate/redundant entries; however some of those row entries have additional columns of data that the master does not, so I don't want to just drop/delete duplicates, but merge them into the master and then drop the duplicates. Does that make sense?